# Sibling properties in Objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c

Is there any Objective C magic I can use to do the following:

Say I have a Class Foo, with two properties myObj A and otherObj B.

Now...

In the Class implementation file (.m) of myObj (A) I want to access 
it's "sibling" property "otherObj B" in the "parent" Class Foo.

Is there something similar to this in objective C to help access sibling properties:

self.ParentClass.b; ?
or
self.OwningClass.b; ?

I know convention is probably to pass a refence to B during init of A, but I don't want to have to create many custom initalisers

Just wondered if there was a shortcut.

```
@interface Foo : NSObject
  @property A
  @property B
@end

@interface A : NSObject
  @property B
@end

@implementation A : NSObject
  self.B = self.parent.B;
@end
```

Thanks,

Comment: Well, you can exploit the singleton design paradigm that keeps track of both properties and their states, and reference that singleton in both implementation files.

Comment: If you don't want to create a custom initialiser, you could set the property when the class is created.

Comment: A and B don't have the same parent. so this doesn't work...

Comment: objC classes are not really javascript prototypes :P

Comment: @Daij-Djan But they are both properties of Foo? so they both have the same parent class (not superclass)

Comment: B is not related to A at all. so they don't have anything in common except they are both classes derived from NSObject

Comment: properties are never static

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no built in "parent" or "owner" concept (large because the object could, theoretically, have strong references to it maintained from multiple objects). But just add your own `parent` property:

Thus, consider:

```
@interface Foo : NSObject

@property (nonatomic, strong) A *a;
@property (nonatomic, strong) B *b;

@end

@interface A : NSObject

@property (nonatomic, weak) Foo *parent;

- (id)initWithParent:(Foo *)foo;

@end

@interface B : NSObject

@property (nonatomic, weak) Foo *parent;

- (id)initWithParent:(Foo *)foo;

@end
```

So, `Foo` will own instances of `A` and `B` objects (thus the `strong` references), and `A` and `B` will maintain a `weak` reference to their parent. Note, the `weak` reference to the parent is critical, to avoid strong reference cycles (a.k.a. retain cycles).

The implementations of these classes might look like:

```
@implementation Foo

- (id)init
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        _a = [[A alloc] initWithParent:self];
        _b = [[B alloc] initWithParent:self];
    }
    return self;
}

@end

@implementation A

- (id)initWithParent:(Foo *)foo
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        _parent = foo;
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)someRandomMethod
{
    B *sibling = self.parent.b;

    // now do whatever you want with your reference to the sibling object
}

@end

@implementation B

- (id)initWithParent:(Foo *)foo
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        _parent = foo;
    }
    return self;
}

@end
```

Notice, in `A` I have a `someRandomMethod` which illustrates how it could get access to its sibling, `B`. You could do the same thing from `B` to `A`, too.

I know you say you don't want to have to write your own custom `init` methods, but that's the right way to do it. Or just call the default `init` method and manually set the `parent` property of the child objects, e.g.:

```
_a = [[A alloc] init];
_a.parent = self;
_b = [[B alloc] init];
_b.parent = self;
```

Answer (score 3):

If you have

```
@interface A : NSObject
@property A
@end

@interface B : NSObject
@property B
@end
```

then A has no way to know B and vice versa. As you said: **you have to pass a reference**

**IF** you ever only have ONE instance of A and ONE instance of B then you COULD use a singleton pattern. But it introduces extra dependencies and makes the code less reusable. so while it might work, thats not a way I would recommend.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I have edited my question- hopefully clearer. I guess I'm trying to ask if there is some easy way to reference the parent of a given property inside the properties implementation, something like a 'self.parent' call?

Comment: A and B don't have the same parent.

Comment: Nah, cause doesn't super refer to the class that was inherited from? I mean the class that 'owns' the properties

Comment: no. that isn't possible in objC. no CLASS owns anything thats not static. instances do

Comment: Cool thanks, and I guess super refers to the class that was inherited from right?

Comment: super refers to the 'your instance of the class you inherited from'

Comment: Thanks, so yes I agree, this won't help in my case, I guess the answer is to pass a reference!